# Data Explorer throws an error for simple select-all query

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

[Create new query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new):
`select * from VoteTypes`
Upon run the following error is returned:

> Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[StackExchange.DataExplorer.Helpers.ResultSet]'.

Comment: My best guess is that the query cache hasn't been cleared since the code updates were applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah ... what Tim said, fixed now